# How programatically disable specific item in network connection properties?

Tags: delphi, network-programming, delphi-10.3-rio, disable, ndis

I want to know if some API/code exists to disable a specific item in the (current) network connection properties?

[image]

If yes, could you show a working code example, explain the details, and point out some limitations (if they exist) of the technique used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API to disable these bindings is [`INetCfgBindingPath::Enable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547700(v=vs.85)).  The [bindview](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/network/config/bindview) sample illustrates how to call the API.

From Windows 8 and later, you may alternatively invoke the WMI method `/root/standardcimv2/MSFT_NetAdapterBindingSettingData::Disable`.  Here's a line of PowerShell that illustrates how to disable the bindings from a NIC named "mb-port" to the "ms_msclient" driver (aka wkssvc):

```bsh
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/standardcimv2 -Query 'SELECT * FROM MSFT_NetAdapterBindingSettingData WHERE Name = "mb-port" AND ComponentID = "ms_msclient"' | Invoke-CimMethod -MethodName Disable
```

Note that the GUI is being sneaky: it merges multiple bindpaths into the same checkbox.  In the example you have highlighted, there are likely 2 bindpaths from ms_msclient to the NIC: one over IPv4 and one over IPv6.  The GUI disables/enables all paths when you clear/tick the checkbox.  If you come in through the API and want to do the same, you'll need to enumerate all bindpaths that start from ms_msclient and go to the NIC mb-port.

Comment: i have a doubt: Saw a [program example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18473911/9708179) where you call [`INetCfg::Apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547947(v=vs.85)) after [`INetCfgBindingPath::Enable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/hardware/network/ff547700(v=vs.85)). This is really mandatory to disable the binding?

Comment: I'm using [this](https://superuser.com/a/1524965) vbscript to list and disable (`objItem.Disable`), but seems that theres not possibility of "`objItem.Apply`".

Comment: INetCfg and MSFT_NetAdapterXxx are different APIs with different designs.  The WMI one is not transactional, so it does not require any sort of `Apply`.